# Inactive Computers Script

Tags: powershell

I wrote a PowerShell script that will check AD for computers that haven't authenticated with it in 30 days.  It will then disable the workstations and move them to another OU.  It will also create a list and export the CSV file to the C:\Custom Folder. However, I need the script to run as administrator.

```
$DaysInactive = 30
$time = (Get-Date).Adddays(-($DaysInactive))
Get-ADComputer -Filter {LastLogonTimeStamp -lt $time} -ResultPageSize 2000 -resultSetSize $null -Properties Name, OperatingSystem, SamAccountName, DistinguishedName | Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=Inactive,OU=Workstations,DC=genericname,DC=genericname,DC=genericname,DC=genericname" -PassThru |Set-ADComputer -Enabled $False -PassThru |Export-Csv -Path "\\SERVERNAME\c$\IT Documentation\Inactive Computers\inactivecomputers.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

I am working on setting the script to run automatically through task scheduler every Friday. How would I need to modify the script to accomplish this?

If I launch PowerShell manually by right clicking and select run as administrator. The script works fine. It's not working through task scheduler though. Any thoughts?

Would I use:

```
Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs
```

If so where would I need to insert it?

Comment: in task scheduler, select the account to use & "highest privs". that should run the script without needing to use `Start-Process`.

Comment: Ok.  I already have that selected.  When its runs i'm geting (0x1) error message.   Under the action tab i have the following configuration program/script: powershell.exe    add arguments: -execution policy bypass c:\scripts\myscript   Start in: c:\scripts.

Comment: i see that you found the source of the glitch. as the old saying goes ... `it's the in the details ...` [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

Good Job. That looks pretty good.

Have a look at [these instructions](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/17736-run-powershell-scripts-from-task-scheduler) to make a scheduled task out of a script. The short of it is, you open the task scheduler and run `powershell.exe` with your script in the arguments.

Keep in mind that you will need to run a job that touches AD as yourself, and if you change your password while this job is enabled, it could lock you out by attempting to log in multiple times.

Comment: OK. It's currently configured to run the script using my AD creds.  It's still getting (0x1) error message.

Comment: Did it work, though? There's no logic in your script to throw, log, or return errors as far as I know. If the job ran and failed, it could just be because it didn't return 0.

Comment: the script works if i manually lauch powershell and run as administrator.  it's failing through task scheduler though.  Do i need to make any changes to the task scheduler. I have it configured to run with my AD creds, run only when user is logged on, & run with highest priviledges.  I also Hidden checked.   Under the action tab i have the following configuration program/script: powershell.exe add arguments: -execution policy bypass c:\scripts\myscript Start in: c:\scripts     is that correct?   Do i need to add anything to the add argument box?

Comment: You can try adding the whole path to the powershell executable if it's in a different place, or your PATH variable isn't set.

Comment: So you are saying add the whole path instead of powershell.exe?

Comment: well i tried the whole path to the powershell executable. No Change.   As far as Path variables.   I am not sure what they should be set to.  I am new to both powershell & using task scheduler to automate commands.  Any assistance would be welcomed

Comment: OK.  I changed the Add Arguments to the following {-execution policy bypass c:\scripts\my script.ps1}    The task schedule says "The operator completed successfully."  However, I am not seeing a new CSV file in the location its configured to save it too.

Comment: Figured it out.  I set the argument as follows   & " 'C:\Scripts\myscript.ps1'"   worked without issues